# Remove special chars from filenames

Tags: bash, find, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I need to remove all special chars from filenames.

Something like `find . -mindepth 1 -exec rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]//g' {} \;` but when rename command renames dir find prints error about no such file or directory (old dir name).

And I need to allow dot.

Comment: If you want to only rename **files** change it to `find . -type f ...` However, the fact you want to permit dot, flies in the face of it being restricted to files only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer of @matias-barrios, I wrote my own solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
fileList=$(find . -mindepth 1)
echo "$fileList" | awk '{print length, $0}' | sort -rn | cut -d" " -f2- | 
while read path; do 
  dirName=$(echo "$path" | rev | cut -d'/' -f2- | rev)
  fileName=$(echo "$path" | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev)
  newFileName="$dirName/$(echo "$fileName" | tr -C -d 'a-zA-Z0-9-_.')"
  if [ "$path" = "$newFileName" ]; then continue; fi;
  echo "From: $path"
  echo "To: $newFileName"
  mv "$path" "$newFileName"
done
```

Comment: Please re-read the link provided @PesaTne on the Q below. Read to the bottom of the supplied article :-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are looking for :

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find /yourdirhere -type f 2>/dev/null);
do
    new_faile_name=$( echo "$file" | tr -C -d '[:graph:]' );
    mv "$file" "$new_faile_name"
done
```

#### EXplanation

This `-d '[:graph:]'` will say delete everything that is printable, and the *-C* will reverse that :  `tr -C -d '[:graph:]'`

This will rename the files :  `mv "$file" "$new_faile_name"`

#### Note : This will do if you want only yo allow capital and lowercase letters plus underscores, hyphens and dots :  `tr -C -d '[a-zA-Z-_.]'`

Regards!

Comment: But I need do it for the entire directory tree.

Comment: Oh no, don't parse `find` with a `for` loop. Read [this](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) to see better solutions.

Comment: I get your point @PesaThe. But although across time I have seen this comment again and again, I have not encountered newlines, or tabs, or other dangerous chars in filenames never on my experience. I mean, If you admin a Linux system and you have files with those characteristics, then you probably have bigger problems everywhere else. Seriously, who does that?!! :O

Comment: Well, this will break for even spaces. And I don't think that is unusual :) To make the solution 100% for any filename is not that difficult. It's just a `while` with `read -d ''` and that's all there is to it.

Comment: @PesaThe Yes, I understand that spaces can be the most usual pitfall for beginners or end users, but for admins this is totally an obvious "NOT TO DO" thing. On the other hand, IMHO, modern Unix/Linux should not allow to create file name outside of "[a-zA-z0-9_-.]" range and that would make everyone lives happier! :)

Comment: This runs afoul of [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: As for "who does that?", it only takes one time you get a random memory buffer dumped into a filename causing one of your scripts to `rm -rf *` to learn caution. (As the shell pedant at the shop where the above happened to our billing-data backups, while it was quite a disaster, it was also quite a lot of "I told you so" fuel).